# How to reduce the amount of logs reported by undetected chromedriver?

Tags: python, undetected-chromedriver

I've written a wrapper for the Undetected Chromedriver.

It works well enough but it generates a huge amount of logs. At least the following for EACH call to the method.

```
2023-04-26 10:14:33: undetected_chromedriver.patcher: INFO: patching driver executable C:\Users\username\appdata\roaming\undetected_chromedriver\undetected_chromedriver.exe
2023-04-26 10:14:34: uc: DEBUG: created a temporary folder in which the user-data (profile) will be stored during this
session, and added it to chrome startup arguments: --user-data-dir=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp156xop2r
2023-04-26 10:14:34: uc: DEBUG: did not find a bad exit_type flag
2023-04-26 10:14:35: uc: INFO: setting properties for headless
2023-04-26 10:14:40: uc: DEBUG: webdriver process ended
2023-04-26 10:14:40: uc: DEBUG: gracefully closed browser
2023-04-26 10:14:40: uc: DEBUG: When removing the temp profile, a PermissionError occured: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp156xop2r\\Default\\Affiliation Database'
retrying...
2023-04-26 10:14:40: uc: DEBUG: successfully removed C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp156xop2r
```

I'm trying to control this in a number of ways:

1. I'm setting the log level for the `undetected chromedriver` to INFO in the logging.yaml file:
2. I'm using `add_argument("--log-level=3")`
3. I'm using `warnings.filterwarnings(...)`
4. I'm setting the `service_log_path` to 'NUL' or '/dev/null' (for Windows and Linux respectively).

### Here's the code to illustrate:

**logging.YAML** (relevant file fragment):

```yaml
  # Point #1 above.
  uc:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [console]
    propagate: no
  undetected-chromedriver:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [console]
    propagate: no
  undetected_chromedriver.patcher:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [console]
    propagate: no
```

**Python wrapper class:**

A wrapper for the code:

```py
import logging
import os
import warnings

import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from environment_helper import EnvironmentHelper
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

# Point #3 above
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="did not find a bad exit_type flag")
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="gracefully closed browser")
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="setting properties for headless")
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="webdriver process ended")


class RequestHelper:
    """
    A helper class for making HTTP requests.
    """

    @staticmethod
    def get(url: str):
        """
        Returns the contents of the page at the specified URL.
        """
        if not url:
            return None

        driver = None
        try:
            timeout = 15

            # Open a browser instance.
            options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            options.add_argument("--disable-default-apps")
            options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
            options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
            options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
            options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
            options.add_argument("--disable-login-animations")
            options.add_argument("--disable-logging")
            options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
            options.add_argument("--dns-prefetch-disable")
            options.add_argument("--headless")
            options.add_argument("--log-level=3")  # # Point #2 above
            options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
            options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")

            # Point #4 above: Setting service_log_path.
            if os.name == "nt":
                service_log_path = "NUL"
            else:
                service_log_path = "/dev/null"
            driver = uc.Chrome(
                options=options, use_subprocess=True, service_log_path=service_log_path
            )
            driver.set_page_load_timeout(timeout)
            driver.get(url)  # @IgnoreException

            contents = driver.page_source

        except TimeoutException as ex:
            logging.warning("Timeout: %s", url)
            return None

        finally:
            if driver:
                try:
                    driver.quit()
                except ProcessLookupError:
                    # This seems to be a known issue with the undetected_chromedriver.
                    pass

        return contents
```

Despite all this effort, I'm still getting an unbearable amount of DEBUG-level output in my logs. How do I get rid of (at least) the DEBUG-level output?